# why my vector.add is adding the string to all outer Vector<Vector<String>>

Tags: java, vector

For java vector operation, get and add, I am confused about my test result:

```
public class temp {
private static Vector<Vector<String>> elems;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int bucketCount = 5;
    elems = new Vector<Vector<String>>(bucketCount);
    int pos = 4;
    String s ="world";

    int elemsSize = elems.size();
    if ( pos >= elemsSize) //grow the outer vector
    {
        Vector<String> empty = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(""));
        for (int i = 0; i<= pos; i++) elems.add(i,empty);
    }

    //APPROACH -1
    Vector<String> v1 = new Vector<String>();
    System.out.println(v1);
    v1= (Vector<String>) elems.get(pos).clone();
    v1.add(0,s);//this does what i want
    System.out.println(v1);
    elems.set(pos, v1);
    System.out.println(elems);
    }
}
```

The above approach I is what i really want to achieve, and it did work:

```
     []
     [world, ]
     [[], [], [], [], [world, ]]
```

if I change the approach 1 to approach 2, below the **somehow** add the string to all outer vector, why output is like below:

```
    []
    [world, ]
    [[world, ], [world, ], [world, ], [world, ], [world, ]]
```

APPROACH - 2 code:

```
    //I thought I am pointing to the 4th outer element by using the elems.get
    Vector<String> l2 = elems.get(pos); 
    System.out.println(l2);
    l2.add(0,s);
    System.out.println(l2);
    elems.set(pos, l2);
    System.out.println(elems);

    //TODO: why the add somehow add the string to all indexes? 
    //even though it was a pointer, it shall point to the right place
```

Comment: Side comment: Vectors are obsolete and you should replace them by ArrayList in most situations...

Comment: I think I sort of know what is happening, so the pointer (i assume) for an empty Vector<String> is all pointing to one place, and the approach 2 (the l2.add(0,s)) will change the data and affect all pointers which point to it. 
During the debug, I found when inner vector is empty, it all has this value "Vector@454" 
and I assume that is the address 

l2 = {Vector@454}  size = 1
 0 = ""
elems = {Vector@451}  size = 5
 0 = {Vector@454}  size = 1
 1 = {Vector@454}  size = 1
  0 = ""
 2 = {Vector@454}  size = 1
 3 = {Vector@454}  size = 1
 4 = {Vector@454}  size = 1
  0 = ""

Comment: Hi assylias,  I thought ArrayList is an interface which is implemented by a few classes such as Vector

Comment: No, List is the interface.